# Background Downloader,Download operation won't start in UWP Windows10?

Tags: windows, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to download files using Background Downloader.
What i have tried is?

```
            FolderPicker folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
            folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
            folderPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
            folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
            StorageFolder storgaeFolder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
            if (storgaeFolder != null)
            {
                StorageFile file = await storgaeFolder.CreateFileAsync("newnow.jpeg", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
                BackgroundDownloader backgroundDownloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
                DownloadOperation downloadOperation = backgroundDownloader.CreateDownload(new Uri("https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwallpapercave.com%2Ffull-hd-wallpaper-downlord&psig=AOvVaw2_UZ_HNVNVr6fJelpyg2-S&ust=1622265707226000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCOCRzOzQ6_ACFQAAAAAdAAAAABAQ"), file);
                downloadOperation.Priority = BackgroundTransferPriority.High;
                Progress<DownloadOperation> progress = new Progress<DownloadOperation>(progressChanged);
                CancellationTokenSource cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
                try
                {
                    await downloadOperation.StartAsync().AsTask(cancellationToken.Token, progress);
                    string xx = null;
                }
                catch (TaskCanceledException)
                {
                    await downloadOperation.ResultFile.DeleteAsync();
                    downloadOperation = null;
                }
            }
           private void progressChanged(DownloadOperation downloadOperation)
          {
            int progress = (int)(100 * ((double)downloadOperation.Progress.BytesReceived /(double)downloadOperation.Progress.TotalBytesToReceive));
            switch (downloadOperation.Progress.Status)
            {
                 case BackgroundTransferStatus.Running:
                {
                    break;
                }
                case BackgroundTransferStatus.PausedByApplication:
                {
                    break;
                }
                case BackgroundTransferStatus.PausedCostedNetwork:
                {
                    break;
                }
                case BackgroundTransferStatus.PausedNoNetwork:
                {
                    break;
                }
                case BackgroundTransferStatus.Error:
                {
                    break;
                }
                case BackgroundTransferStatus.Completed:
                {
                    break;
                }
                case BackgroundTransferStatus.Canceled:
                {
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    break;
                }
        }
        if (progress >= 100)
        {
            downloadOperation = null;
        }
        
      }
```

the execution stopped/paused at the line ---> await downloadOperation.StartAsync().The program won't run after this line and the download operation doesn't through any BackgrowndTransferStatus or Exceptions.I don't know why the code won't run after the line.

Comment: Have you checked if the network is available? and have you tested with official code [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundTransfer)

Comment: And I checked your uri, it looks can't be download directly.

Comment: Oh! Sorry. Use this url "https://www.pexels.com/photo/65894/download/?search_query=free%20download&tracking_id=pcy5lul4wvm"

Comment: Have you tested with official code sample ?

Comment: I make sample with above code, and it could download the file with comment uri.

Comment: but,for me it won't work!!

Comment: I guess it's network issue, please try to test with other machine.

Comment: I creat new project,and i use the official code https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundTransfer and it works fine.But in our app Project it won't work

Comment: At the same time,i tested in different machine,there also  won't work

Comment: Is there any error throw from above code ?

Comment: No , It won't throw any error.